# I can't connect to my SQL server using my public IP

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, sql-server, sql

As of now, I am currently using **SQL Server Management**. I can connect to my SQL Server hosted on a different computer on the network. For explaining purposes, my computer is **computer A** and the computer that is hosting the SQL Server is called **computer B**. I can connect to the SQL server from computer A from the server name being **DESKTOP\SQLdatabase** and the login being the default **sa**. I can also connect with the ipv4 address of the computer which is 192.168.1.191 with the server name being **192.168.1.191,1433**, using computer **A and B**. I can never login through the IP of the router which comes from https://nordvpn.com/what-is-my-ip/. I have port forwarded the sql server and here is a picture of how it looks like.

[A picture of the router with the two rules that I added to port forward it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36tul.png)

I can connect to the SQL server from **computer A** using the **ipv4** address of it, not the router's one. Every time I try to join using the router's IP, it says this:

**Connect to Server**

Cannot connect to x.x.x.x

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476

**The network path was not found**

I have tried to access the SQL server for example like this:

Server name: x.x.x.x
User: sa
Password: 123

Server name: x.x.x.x,1433
User: sa
Password: 123

(x.x.x.x stands for the real IP, I'm not using the default gateway or anything like that)
and some other ways I can't remember at the moment.

First off, I have recently installed a SQL Server (Developer version) from Microsoft on a **computer B**. I have looked over a lot of videos and threads from websites like this or stackoverflow. None of their solutions have helped me and have done them over thousands of times.

I have already did the following:

> Enabled **TCP/IP Protocol** and set it to nothing.
>
> In **IPAll**, I Turned **TCP Dynamic Ports** to nothing
>
> I have also set the **TCP Port** to **1433**
>
> Every**IPn** is **Enabled** and **Active** on the TCP/IP Protocol
>
> Port forwarded it, including the SQL Server Browser.

And yes, I did restart the **SQL Server Service**.

I think that there is something wrong with the port forwarding because I can access it with computers in my network but when I try to access it by the router's IP, it says that it is not found.
I have disabled the firewall incase that was the issue but, the issue still happens. 
**Therefore I'm positive that it has to do something with the port forwarding.**
I have put **TCP and UDP** in case that might of been the problem and I have also included the SQL Server Browser.

Comment: Generally, exposing your SQL Server to the internet is not advised from a security perspective. You should anticipate that bad actors scanning the internet will find your SQL Server and attempt to brute-force their way into the sa account.

Comment: This sounds like it is almost certainly a networking problem--either with your router configuration, or your ISP. Its possible they are doing something to your inbound traffic that prevents you from connecting.  Have you tried connecting on some other port/service?

Comment: I plan on having different accounts and this SQL server is just to test on. I want people that I know to be able to access it.
Should I change the port to some other random port that is not used like 1660?
I will double check the router for any odd configurations.

Comment: @AMtwo I have figured out that I have port forwarded it correctly but, I can't log onto my SQL server from my external IP. I have looked through plenty of threads and still haven't found a solution. I can basically join in from my internal ip ( 192.168.x.x ) but, if I try with my external ip ( 12.34.567.891 ), it wouldn't connect. I have even disabled the firewall for this situation and it still doesn't work. Do you have any idea of how to enable my self to be able to connect to the sql server while being on my network but connecting through the external IP of the router?

Comment: SQL Server does not have any sort of built in firewall. The error message posted on your original question is coming from the client to say it's not finding a SQL Instance at the specified address. There is some networking/firewall issue. If Windows firewall is off, then it's likely either your router config, your ISP, or something on the client end. I'm a SQL Server guy and I can say that this isn't a SQL Server issue. Have you tried connecting to some other service or port? RDP or some webserver?

Comment: You say "I have figured out that I have port forwarded it correctly" ... If suggest you update your question with details on how you confirmed this. As your question is currently written, router/firewall misconfiguration remains the most likely problem. Any troubleshooting you have done on that front is very relevant.

Comment: @AMtwo I have done a little bit more research and I found out my port is opened by canyouseeme.org and by enabling/disabling my port forwarding rules while checking if my ports are opened through the website mentioned above. I have verified the I correctly port forwarded the server but I think that my router doesn't support NAT loopback so I have to connect through the internal ip 192.168.x.x when I want to join the server. From what I see my router doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons of the "Microsoft sql server error 53" can appear because client cannot resolve the name of the server or the name of the server is incorrect.

You can try to troubleshoot the network regarding if you can resolve the name of the server or to try to Ping and telnet the server and host.

You can check about sql server error 40 the following source - https://www.get-itsolutions.com/sql-server-error-26-sql-error-40-fix/

for error 53 the following link: https://www.get-itsolutions.com/microsoft-sql-server-error-53/

Thnx